# What does the epitaph on Alexander Row's tombstone say?

Tags: last-exile

The captain of the Silvana, Alexander Row, died heroically after killing Delphine with his bare hands. He was buried with a very modest tombstone with an epitaph in some language. What does the epitaph say?

[image: Epitaph]

Answer (score 1):

A quick search in wikia tells me that:

Alex's epitaph, "Κοιμάστε αιώνια," means "eternal rest" in Greek.

http://lastexile.wikia.com/wiki/Alexander_Row